# jqplot is not updating chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have been strugling with my code for a couple of days now. I have researched the Internet and read the docs. I have tried what I could find in code that others present in answers to similar questions.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">if (typeof jQuery == "undefined"){document.write("<script src='jqplot/jquery.min.js' language='javascript' type='text/javascript'><\/script>");}</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language=javascript>

        $(document).ready(function(){

        var plot1 = null;
        var line1=[['2008-09-30 4:00PM',4], ['2008-10-30 4:00PM',6.5], ['2008-11-30 4:00PM',5.7], ['2008-12-30 4:00PM',9], ['2009-01-30 4:00PM',8.2]];
        var line2=[['2008-09-30 4:00PM',8], ['2008-11-05 4:00PM',3], ['2008-11-30 4:00PM',7], ['2008-12-30 4:00PM',9], ['2009-01-30 4:00PM',8.2]];

        plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [line1], {
                    title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
            axes: {
              xaxis: {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,

              },
              yaxis: {
              }
            },
            highlighter: {
              show:true
            },
            cursor:{
              show:true,
              zoom:true
            } 

          });

        alert("wait");


        plot1.series[0].data=[line2];
        plot1.replot();


        }); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I just want to update the chart from data in line1 to data in line2.
As it is the result is an empty chart.

The purpose of this exercise is to later change the code to update the graph via data acquired with json from the server. That part is working. In the end I would like to plot a dataset with 1500 points.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Leon

Comment: After posting my question here, I was able to let go and ..... eventually found how to go about it. If you specify the date not as a string but as the serial number (i.e. the milliseconds since epoch, 1970), the graph just replots beautifully.